# Problem installing Android SDK on Eclipse Galileo

Tags: development, eclipse, sdk, debug

I am using Kubuntu 10.10 and Eclipse Galileo and am trying to install the SDK. I am following the instructions provided at http://developer.android.com.

The step where my Eclipse detects the plugin after installing fails i.e. After downloading and installing, when I click Window->Preferences, I am not able to see any android tab to the left.

Searched online, googled it, but am not able to find a solution. What do I do ?

Comment: So you downloaded the Linux SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk and unpacked  it somewhere on your file system before you installed the Eclipse plugin (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)? Not trying to be pedantic, but there are a lot of instructions alongside the SDK and I want to know that we're talking about the same thing. 

Have you successfully installed Eclipse plugins in the past?  

Does the error log in Eclipse shed any light on the issue?

Comment: @Amanda: Yes. I am following the same instructions. I encounter a problem in the 2nd step of "Configuring the ADT plugin", i.e. "Select Android from the left panel". Android does not appear on the left panel. I saw some screenshots online how it is supposed to appear, but that does not happen for me.

For your 2nd question, No. I downloaded Eclipse only to get onto learning to develop Android apps and I have not installed any other plugin in the past.

Comment: @Anirudh, it sounds like you need help troubleshooting Eclipse first, which might be beyond the scope of this forum, unfortunately.

Comment: @Al: I'm inclined to agree with JonnyP/Matthew Read given that the *only* tag the OP put on this question was "development" (and based on his follow-up comment).

Comment: @Amanda, I even tried reinstalling Eclipse a few times. I am able to find the necessary plugins under "Installed Software". They are even upto date. But not able to find Android tab under Preferences... Frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting the process over again, and making sure you meet every requirement and hit every step. Don't skip anything.

Comment: I went through every step thrice. Must be some problem with my distro itself (kubuntu).

Comment: That's really interesting. I'm sorry you're having so much trouble... try to update Eclipse, and make sure you have the Sun JDK. That's the one I've always made it a point to use, and the one Google recommends. If Eclipse is trying to use OpenJDK, that might be a problem. Other than that, has Eclipse successfully downloaded the ADT plugin?